# Unable to select bones in pose mode (Blender 2.8)

Tags: armature, bones, pose-mode

This question has been asked a few times in various forms here, but none of the solutions work for me. I have included a short video showing the issue, where I highlight everything.

https://youtu.be/OP9Q6qG978s

Video broken down:

- Brand new install of 2.8 (even deleted the data in Appdata/Roaming/Blender Foundation/2.80)
- Restriction Toggle for the armature is not disabled
- 'Lock Object Modes' in Pose Mode whether On or Off doesn't fix it
- Unparenting the mesh from the armature and reparenting doesn't fix it

Something I forgot to say in the video, importing that character mesh into 2.79 works and doesn't have any of these problems (opening a saved 2.79 project in 2.80 does not fix it either). Same with other character meshes I have tested.

I genuinely don't know what to do, and neither do my buddies who work with Blender regularly. I have been trying to fix this for 3 days now, and I am very frustrated as it's preventing me from working with any armatures.

[Can't Select Bones in Pose Mode (Blender 2.8)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136580/cant-select-bones-in-pose-mode-blender-2-8?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[I can't keep my armature in pose mode when selecting another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127805/i-cant-keep-my-armature-in-pose-mode-when-selecting-another-object)

[Why can't I select bones in pose mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38949/why-cant-i-select-bones-in-pose-mode)

Answer (score 10):

Try to **disable** "In Front" in Viewport Display in the Armature Tab - that worked for me

[image]

Comment: This worked for me also.... as did circle select mentioned in another answer.

Comment: This issue seems to occur on a per-file basis. I managed to fix it in a file by playing around with the "`Local View`" (Num Pad `[/]`), "`X-Ray`" (`<Alt>[Z]`), "`In Front`", "`Display As`", and "`In Front (Animate property)`" (Object Properties) options. I can click to select bones again afterwards, even with "In Front" on, but I had to restart Blender to click the 3D view panel widgets. It didn't work until after I'd enabled and disabled the "Animate" diamond for "In Front" either.

Comment: For reference, here is a thread on BlenderArtists with other people's findings: 
https://blenderartists.org/t/unable-to-select-bones-in-pose-mode-blender-2-8/1168325/

Here is a linked bug ticket that is supposed to have been resolved: 
https://developer.blender.org/T65221

Answer (score 0):

I had his same problem. So apparently this bug happens when you start a file with an older version of Blender and then load it into 2.8. What I would do is open a new blank file and just "append" or import it from your older file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time. It seems that you can select individual bones using the *Select Circle* tool instead of the standard *Select*.

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a bug or if it means that we should use it from now on. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just a moment ago. Imported character were working, but their duplicate pose was unselectable. I saved and restarted the software and it is now working. A bad answer but we all forget to do it first.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a character I'm rigging, only *Circle Select* and *Select All* worked.

I found that turning off *In Front* on my armature fixed the issue.

My armature was still in front of my mesh, turns out I had *X-Ray* on as well, the combination of that and *In Front* caused my bones to be unable to be selected with box select mode.